# Solana , Signature verification error magic eden

Tags: nft, solana-web3js

I am trying to purchase NFT on MagicEden. this is my code

Prepare signers

```
let Array_key = [123:..:98];
 
let signers = Keypair.fromSecretKey(Uint8Array.from(Array_key))
```

Connection

```
const connection = new Connection("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com",'confirmed');
```

Get Instruction data from MagicEden

```
let get_seller_details:any = await this.get_seller_details(MintAddress, this.myTask);

let get_seller_details_json = JSON.parse(get_seller_details.text);

let seller = get_seller_details_json[0].seller;
let sellerReferral = get_seller_details_json[0].sellerReferral;
let tokenATA = get_seller_details_json[0].tokenAddress;
let buyer = this.WalletAddress;
```

MagicEden  [tx][data] response

```
let buy_response:any = await this.Prepare_buyer_transaction(MintAddress, AuctionHouseAddress, buyer, seller, tokenATA, sellerReferral, Price, this.myTask);


let parsed_buy_response = JSON.parse(buy_response.text);
```

Transaction
const data = Transaction.populate(Message.from(parsed_buy_response['tx']['data']));

```
await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, data, [signers]).then(resolve => {
    console.log('transaction send and conferming')
    console.log(resolve)
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log('err at confirm transaction')
    console.log(err)
  })
```

But I get an Error: Signature Verification failed